# Strange \AtBegShi@Output warning in case of special .xdy style file that is supposed to make (tex)xindy and hyperref happy together

Tags: hyperref, indexing, warnings, xindy

Consider the following MWE (thanks to [this nice article](http://geekographie.maieul.net/172) from Maïeul Rouquette (in French)) that makes possible to have both:

- indices built with `(tex)xindy`,
- hyperlinked page numbers and "see",

(named, say, `test.tex`):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.xdy}
(markup-keyword-list :open "\targetindexentry{" :close "}" )
(markup-crossref-list :class "see" :open "\seelink{" :sep "; " :close "}{}")

(define-crossref-class "hyperindexformat")
(markup-crossref-list :class "hyperindexformat" :open
      "\hyperindexformat{" :sep "; " :close "}{}")

(markup-locref :open "\hyperpage{" :close "}")
(markup-locref :open "\hyperpage{" :close "}" :attr "hyperpage")
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\pdftex_if_engine:TF
  {
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  }{
    \usepackage{fontspec}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\usepackage[hyperindex=false]{hyperref}%
%
\newcommand{\targetindexentry}[1]{\hypertarget{index:#1}{#1}}
\newcommand{\seelink}[1]{\see{\hyperlink{index:#1}{#1}}}
%
\makeindex[options=-M \jobname.xdy]
%
\begin{document}
Foo%
\index{café!bar}%
\index{bar}%
%
\printindex
%
\end{document}
```

If it is compiled with:

1. `pdflatex test` (or `lualatex test` or `xelatex test`),
2. `texindy -M test.xdy test.idx`
3. `pdflatex test` (or `lualatex test` or `xelatex test`),

we notice 3 different behaviors:

- with `pdflatex`, there is a warning (which is not really informative but seems to be serious):

  > pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{index:bar})
  >   has been already used, duplicate ignored
  >   \AtBegShi@Output ...ipout \box \AtBeginShipoutBox 
  >                                                 \fi \fi 
  >   l.39 \end{document}
- with `lualatex`, there is a warning:

  > warning  (pdf backend): ignoring duplicate destination with the name 'index:bar
  >   '
- with `xelatex`, everything's okay.

I guess the warning with `pdflatex` comes from the LICR in the `.ind` file:

```
\begin{theindex}
  \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
  \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
      \par\textbf{#1}\par
      \nopagebreak
  }

  \lettergroup{B}
  \item \targetindexentry{bar}, \hyperpage{1}

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{C}
  \item \targetindexentry{caf\IeC {\'e}}
    \subitem \targetindexentry{bar}, \hyperpage{1}

\end{theindex}
```

Here is my question(s):

How to get rid of the warning in `pdflatex` (and also in `lualatex`) case? (And how do you explain the differences between `xelatex` and `lualatex` while the `.ind` file is the same in both cases?)

Comment: The warning is correct: There are two link targets with the same name `index:bar` under letter B and C. Therefore, the item for the subitems should be included in the target name, because the subitem name is not unique.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Okay, I'll try to figure out how to include the item as well. Can we consider as a bug the fact `xelatex` doesn't tell anything about this?

Comment: Call it bug, missing feature or whatever. As long as nobody invests time to implement the warning in XeTeX, nothing will change.